# Populating an immutable List

Tags: scala

Here I populate two Lists where each list is either mutable or immutable :

```
var mutableList = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String]()
                                                  //> mutableList  : scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String] = MutableList()
                                                  //| 

  for (a <- 1 to 100) {
    mutableList += a.toString
  }

  println(mutableList.size);                      //> 100
  val immutableList = List[String]()              //> immutableList  : List[String] = List()

  for (a <- 1 to 100) {
    immutableList :+ a.toString
  }

  println(immutableList.size);                    //> 0
```

When I print the size of the immutableList its output is 0. This is because within the for loop a new reference is created that does not point to immutableList ? Is there a functional equivalent to populating an immutable List from within loop ?

Comment: `fold`(Left/Right) is what you are looking for (or /tail recursive/ recursion). (Or just `to[List]` after a `map`.)

Answer (score 3):

As Gabor answered in a comment, you want to use `fold`, or even continue with the for and `yield`. What he did not explain is why you are getting a size of 0. The reason is that `immutableList :+ a.toString` is returning a new list each time, which you are not using. the `immutableList` is exactly that, immutable.

Keep in mind that everything in Scala is an expression and therefore returns something. So, you can turn your regular `for` (which acts like a `forEach`) into a comprehension by adding the `yield` as below

```
  val immutableList = for (a <- 1 to 100) yield a.toString
```

This desugars into something like:

```
(1 to 100).map(_.toString)
```

Comment: As an aside, most of scala's immutable collections offer a `newBuilder` method on their companion objects, e.g. `val lb = List.newBuilder[Int]; ... ; val immutableList = lb.result`

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, method `tabulate` allows for creating and populating an immutable `List`, for instance as follows,

```
List.tabulate(100)(a => a.toString)
```

or equivalently

```
List.tabulate(100)(_.toString)
```